# Null folder created when executing a Kettle job

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I'm running a kettle job which calls another job and then a transformation, the job runs smoothly in the PDI Spoon but when i call the job via a kitchen job it throws

```
2016/03/07 20:51:50 - Purifier_success - Executing command :
/home/ubuntu/dataintegration/data-integration/null/kettle_6a3db0e2-e4a6-11e5-b201-d7ec3590f1c5shell
2016/03/07 20:51:50 - Purifier_success - ERROR (version 5.4.0.1-130,
build 1 from 2015-06-14_12-34-55 by buildguy) : (stderr)
/home/ubuntu/dataintegration/data-integration/null/kettle_6a3db0e2-e4a6-11e5-b201-d7ec3590f1c5shell:
1:
/home/ubuntu/dataintegration/data-integration/null/kettle_6a3db0e2-e4a6-11e5-b201-d7ec3590f1c5shell:
2016/03/07 20:51:50 - Purifier_success - ERROR (version 5.4.0.1-130,
build 1 from 2015-06-14_12-34-55 by buildguy) : (stderr) : not found
```

But the job runs successfully. But its awkward to see to see the shell screen saying error.
Is there any way to solve it.

Comment: Are you calling an external command?

Comment: No, I'm calling the KJB from kitchen, which i did in a shell

Comment: Are you calling an external command in your transformation?

Comment: how you are executing it? give some more details.

Comment: When you run it in spoon what do you see that path containing instead of the null?  Suspect in spoon you have an env var or parameter set which you don't have with kitchen.